# Fourier Series of a sum of two functions

Tags: fourier-series

Is the Fourier series of a  sum of two functions $f,g$ the term by term sum of the Fourier Series?

Comment: Yep, provided these sums converge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes because of the linearity of integration.